# WebGL error - INVALID_VALUE: shaderSource: string not ASCII

Tags: glsl, webgl, glslify

Hi i am trying to use WebGl technology for my react app using three.js and glslify.
I tried the code below but got error - *INVALID_VALUE: shaderSource: string not ASCII.*

I tried to find the way to solve it but there was not any result that fits my problem.
How can i solve it?

```
glslify(`
          precision mediump float;
          #define LUT_FLIP_Y

          varying vec2 vUv;
          uniform sampler2D tDiffuse;
          uniform sampler2D tLookup;

          #pragma glslify: lut = require('glsl-lut')

          void main () {
            gl_FragColor = texture2D(tDiffuse, vUv);
            gl_FragColor.rgb = lut(gl_FragColor, tLookup).rgb;
          }
`)
```

Comment: From the documentation of glslify that I've seen, you should be using ```glsl(`...`)``` or ```glsl`...` ``` instead of ```glslify(`...`)```

Comment: ... that same documentation brings in glslify with `var glsl = require('glslify')`.  It is difficult to determine any further issues in the code without a more-complete example.

Comment: `glslify` is a build time plugin for webpack/browserify/rollup etc. Show how you have your build configured (read the docs for glslify) then show us both the source and the build results in the quesiton itself.

Comment: @whydoubt i imported glslify as `var glslify = require('glslify')`.. so it doesn't matter

Comment: i found some new info using firefox console(which chrome does not give. lol) it says the problem was the caracter single quiote(') but i still don't know why this is problem..